# Adding sections/dividers in React Native Navigation Drawer

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, navigation-drawer, react-navigation-drawer

I have a React Native project using a React Navigation Drawer, using a custom drawer component:

```
const CustomDrawerContentComponent = (props) => (
    <Container>
        <Header androidStatusBarColor={Colors.BlueDark} title="Title" style={styles.drawerHeader} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')}>
            <Body style={styles.container}>
                <LogoCircle size={15} />
                <Container style={styles.drawerTextContainer}>
                    <Text style={styles.drawerText}>My App</Text>
                </Container>
            </Body>
        </Header>
        <Content>
            <DrawerItems {...props} />
        </Content>
    </Container>
);
```

Is it possible to add dividers to make sections of drawer items? I would like to have half of my items in one section, and the other half in another, split by a divider.

I know it is possible to create custom drawer entries that navigate to certain pages on press, but in this case I cannot use styling such as "activeBackgroundColor".

Comment: left/right or top/bottom section?

Comment: @digit Top/Bottom section. For example, my first section would have "Home" and "Profile", followed by a divider, followed by my second section with "Settings"